# How can User login only with email ending with @uae.com using WPF C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have created a login page in my application window, what I need is there any code,  users can only login if their emails end with ......@uae.com, otherwise (messagebox.show("Sorry, you can't login")).

> Mainwindow.xaml.cs code

```
 private void btn_Login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(btn_Email.Text.Length==0)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Your Email!");
                btn_Email.Focus();
            }
            else if (!Regex.IsMatch(btn_Email.Text, @"^[a-zA-Z][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]$"))
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Valid Email!");
                btn_Email.Select(0, btn_Email.Text.Length);
                btn_Email.Focus();
            }
            if (btn_Password.Password == "")
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Password!");
            }
            else if (btn_Password.Password == "maryam")
            {
                MainWindow home = new MainWindow();
                home.Show();
                this.Close();
            }
            else
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Wrong Password!","Error!",MessageBoxButton.OK, (MessageBoxImage)MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following check:

```
if (!btn_Email.Text.EndsWith("@uae.com"))
{
  Messagebox.show("Sorry, you can't login");
  return;
}
```

after the email check